# Iterating through a list broken into chunks

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a chunked list that contains the following:

```
ChunkedList = ['2018-12-14 15:00:00', 'A : aa1', 'B: bb2', 'C: cc3'] ['2018-12-14 16:00:00', 'A : aa2', 'B: bb2','C: cc1']['2018-12-14 17:00:00', 'A : aa3', 'B: bb1','C: cc3']['2018-12-14 18:00:00', 'A : aa3', 'B: bb1','C: cc3']['2018-12-14 19:00:00', 'A : aa3', 'B: bb1','C: cc3']['2018-12-14 20:00:00', 'A : aa3', 'B: bb1','C: cc3']
```

If I run the following code on an unchunked list, I get the individual lines that include the relevant times.

```
import datetime
hours = [(datetime.time(i).strftime('%H:%M:%S')) for i in range(6,18)]
WFList = [line for line in FullList if any(hour in line for hour in hours)]
```

Like this:

```
WFList= ['2018-12-14 15:00:00','2018-12-14 16:00:00','2018-12-14 17:00:00']
```

My current code for the chunked list is:

```
for chunk in ChunkedList:
    if any(hour in chunk for hour in hours):
        print(chunk)
```

It returns nothing. I would like to get back a list with the chunks containing the times in my range like below:

```
IdealList = ['2018-12-14 15:00:00', 'A : aa1', 'B: bb2', 'C: cc3'] ['2018-12-14 16:00:00', 'A : aa2', 'B: bb2','C: cc1']['2018-12-14 17:00:00', 'A : aa3', 'B: bb1','C: cc3']
```

I read through quite a few posts regarding iteration and chunked lists and am stumped. Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Your input is formatted a bit weirdly since you need `list` of `list`s to store the data.

Comment: Your chunked list looks like it would be better off as a list of dictionaries. `[{'date':'2018-12-14 15:00:00', 'A': 'aa1', 'B': 'bb2', 'C': 'cc3'}, ...]`

Comment: I was thinking about that. What are the benefits of using a list of dictionaries over a list of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `hours` contains strictly the time. While your list contains both `date` and `time`. You need to use `split` method for strings to parse your list. Try this:

```
import datetime

hours = [(datetime.time(i).strftime('%H:%M:%S')) for i in range(6,18)]

ChunkedList = [['2018-12-14 15:00:00', 'A : aa1', 'B: bb2', 'C: cc3'],
               ['2018-12-14 16:00:00', 'A : aa2', 'B: bb2','C: cc1'],
               ['2018-12-14 17:00:00', 'A : aa3', 'B: bb1','C: cc3'],
               ['2018-12-14 18:00:00', 'A : aa3', 'B: bb1','C: cc3'],
               ['2018-12-14 19:00:00', 'A : aa3', 'B: bb1','C: cc3'],
               ['2018-12-14 20:00:00', 'A : aa3', 'B: bb1','C: cc3']]

result = [big_list for big_list in ChunkedList if big_list[0].split()[1] in hours]
# [['2018-12-14 15:00:00', 'A : aa1', 'B: bb2', 'C: cc3'], ['2018-12-14 16:00:00', 'A : aa2', 'B: bb2', 'C: cc1'], ['2018-12-14 17:00:00', 'A : aa3', 'B: bb1', 'C: cc3']]
```

`big_list[0].split()[1]` looks only at the time to see if it is inside the range provided in `hours`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked to solve my problem. It is strange that on an unchunked list it was able to pull out the line details using just the time.

Comment: No problem. What do you mean by "unchunked" list?